# WPF child page get parent frame

Tags: wpf, navigation, frame

I have a parent frame Frame1 that opens a page Page1. From Page1 I want to click a button and direct Frame1 to open a new page Page2. Is this navigation method feasible? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my Frame is in main window, I've solved using the following method. A more standardized approach after I read a few more articles would probably use MVVM way
Put this code at Page1:

```
 Dim myWindow As Window1 = TryCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, Window1)
     If myWindow IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim myFrame As Frame = myWindow.Frame1

        myFrame.Navigate(New Page2())
     End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available:

1) You can give Page1 a reference to Frame1 when you create it, or after creation.
2) You can use GetWindow(this) to get a reference to the window which Page1 is contained in
3) You can use events; make Frame1 listen to event OpenPage2
4) You can use commands, and listen to them, sort of like events.

Of these, the events and commands approaches are probably best.

Comment: @AkseIK, is it possible for you to create a sample code for method 3) and 4)? I tried creating a Public Sub OpenPage2 at Frame1.vb file but I can't see this function at Page1

Comment: I don't know VB syntax, so I cannot help you there. But you must declare the event OpenPage2 in Page1, and in Frame 1, listen to that event (Page1.OpenPage2 += new OpenPage2Event(doOpenPage);) And then, when you invoke the event OpenPage2 in Page1, the method doOpenPage will run. For more information, read up on events here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx

Comment: I've tired the event method that you suggested. Created a new object class Frame1 inside Page1 and call a public function in Frame1 that executes Frame1.Navigate(New Page2()). From debugging, this line of code is executed but the content of Frame1 is not refreshed and still showing Page1 instead of Page2. Added NavigationService.Refresh() but still no changes....